# What is a Plex data structure?

Tags: data-structures, abstract-data-type

What is a Plex in terms of data structure? 
I read this question somewhere

```
Which of the following abstract data types can be used to 
represent a many-to-many relation?
 (a) Tree.      (b) Plex
 (c) Graph.     (d) Both (b) and (c)
```

The correct option was (d).
I googled the term but not found anything that explains it in simpler terms.

Comment: Plex can be used to represent Directed graph as well, hence it can be used to represent many-to-many relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my understanding from this [site](http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/acl/literature/books/compilingtechniques/p002.htm):

A Plex data structure, is like a linked list of n-sized arrays. Where each array is called as `Bead` and each bead can contain either *information* or a *pointer* to another bead.

It is a more efficient data structure alternative used to represent an "intricate network of *interrelated parts*".

Here's an example taken from the same site:

[image: Plex data Structure]

Answer (score 2):

A plex (derived from plexus meaning any complex structure containing an intricate network of interrelated parts) consists of a set of elements called beads, where each element is an N-word vector of computer storage.

> **Storage systems similar to the plex have been in wide use for a number of years;** a precise definition and theory of plexes and plex programming is due to D. T. Ross of the Massachusetts Institute of Technology.

reference:
http://www.chilton-computing.org.uk/acl/literature/books/compilingtechniques/p002.htm